# Move a file from one directory to another

Tags: c#, directory, move

I created a zip file/folder with DotNetZip. I'm trying to move that file from the original directory/folder to another, e.g. My Documents. So far I have done the following, but it gives me an error saying that it could not find part of the path.

```
private static void Move()
{
    try
    {
        Directory.Move(@"Debug\Settings.zip", IO.Paths.Enviroment.MyDocuments);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
So I've played with it a bit and laughed not because I fixed it but because it's weird. I used both `File.Move()` and `Directory.Move()` and changed `both.Move(@"Debug\Settings.zip",...);` to `both.Move(@"Settings.zip",...);` and then get get an an error saying `Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`

[image: Directory Tree]

Comment: This is not specific to zip files, of course.

Answer (score 2):

While it may seem strange to use [`Directory.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx) to move a file, (I'd use [`File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) instead), [Jean-Philippe Leclerc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613568/jean-philippe-leclerc) points out that it will work.

The problem is with the path `Debug\Settings.zip`:

All relative paths are relative to the working directory. By default the working directory is the folder in which the assembly (your program) is executed, and while debugging that is the `bin\Debug` subfolder of your project. So your path `Debug\Settings.zip` is expanded to a path like:

```
C:\..\MyProject\bin\Debug\Debug\Settings.zip
```

This is probably not what you meant. You meant just `"Settings.zip"`.

The fact that it's a ZIP is irrelevant.

Comment: According to the official documentation. Directory.Move works with files: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx

Comment: Didn't know that. Now my question is: why would you ever want to use `File.Move` when `Directory.Move` already does whatever you want?

Comment: Because with Directory.Move can accidently the whole directory when you only want to move a file. So File.Move prevents human errors.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc - can you explain accidently?

Comment: You know, when "you accidently the whole thing". Lets say that you have some code that generates some file path but it ends up that your generated path is a directory because your algo is bad. In that situation, you want the program to throw an exception, not to move your directory.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc - got ya, thnx, i took accidentally for something else!

Answer (score 1):

**`could not find part of the path`** - The error seems like the `Relative Path` to your file `Settings.Zip` is not a valid path!

---

You need to use `File.Move`, `Directory.Move` will move the entire content of the Directory to different folder.

`File.Move` : Only moves the file to a specified location

```
private static void Move()
        {
            try
            {
                File.Move(@"Debug\Settings.zip", System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, apparently [`Directory.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx) will also move files. :P

Comment: @Virtlink - the only difference between them is, File.Move cannot handle directory move operation!

Comment: @AppDeveloper, @Virtlink Well I've debated myself if a .zip was a file or folder...I thought it would be a "Directory" because it technically is a folder that contains the folders and files but some refer .zip as a file. So I used `Directory.Move()` and tried it. But as far the relative path. I've tried both `Directory` and `File` but it doesn't seem to see the `Settings.zip` folder/file when I know it's there because I'm looking at it right now lol.

Comment: @iwatakeshi - can u show us a screen snap of directory tree in which application is kept?

Comment: @iwatakeshi - zip is not a directory, it is a file, u can think of it same as ISO file, Setup Installer, they have bundle of files!

Comment: @AppDeveloper Interesting. I posted the picture up top.

Comment: the application is kept in `Debug` folder?

Comment: i still dont see the Settings.zip in the screensnap!

Comment: @AppDeveloper Yes. As as far the .zip file, I deleted it since I have been using trial and error to see where the issue was. But, I fixed it eventually. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Use **System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)** to get your MyDocuments path.

Comment: +1 I think this should be the correct answer because Directory.Move works with files too.

Comment: -1: The problem is not with the my documents path. First, he gets it from _some location we all don't know_ (`Paths.Enviroment.MyDocuments`) and it is probably a string otherwise it would not work. Second, the problem is with the other argument.

Comment: @Virtlink The string `Paths.Enviroment.MyDocuments` is `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`, I just made my life easier by creating my own Enviroment class with a static string returning the My Documents path lol. The other part `@"Debug\Settings.zip` refers to the visual studio's project's Debug folder. There is a folder called Settings in the Debug folder that I zipped up. I just wanted to move the zipped folder to another location, which in this case would be My Documents.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! The issues were first the `"Debug\Settings.zip"` should have been `"Settings.zip"` or `@"Settings.zip"` and finally destination should not just be `System.IO.File.Move(@"Settings.zip", System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));` but `System.IO.File.Move(@"Settings.zip", System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\Settings.zip");` Basically, add the file name and the extension of the file at the end of the destination string.